# "cordova run ios " in Windows not works

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I install "ionic cordova run ios" on my PC (Windows 10) but I got an error message
"[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova."
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You cannot run ionic ios app in Windows. you should use Mac for it.

Answer (score 1):

To build an app for iOS you need to have the xcode command line tools  installed. Cordova looks for these tools before building. If you don't have that, you can't build your app for iOS.

If you want to build your app for iOS you'll need a Mac with xcode and Cordova installed. Or you could use a virtual machine to do it. For more information on the virtual machine option have look [here](https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/)

Comment: Actually you only need XCode command line tools to build an app. When you install XCode they get installed with it, but only the command line tools are sufficient.